# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Excuse me, and I tried to build an APK with the command

```
ionic cordova build android --debug
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-identity.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-api-phone.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone/11.8.0/play-services-auth-api-phone-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base/11.8.0/play-services-auth-base-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-identity-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity-license/11.8.0/play-services-identity-license-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-api-phone-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone-license/11.8.0/play-services-auth-api-phone-license-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base-license/11.8.0/play-services-auth-base-license-11.8.0.aar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
(node:440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /home/alain/PuntoPro/PuntoPro/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-identity.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-api-phone.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone/11.8.0/play-services-auth-api-phone-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base/11.8.0/play-services-auth-base-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-identity-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity-license/11.8.0/play-services-identity-license-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-api-phone-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone-license/11.8.0/play-services-auth-api-phone-license-11.8.0.aar
  >   Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base-license/11.8.0/play-services-auth-base-license-11.8.0.aar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/alain/PuntoPro/PuntoPro/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:440) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I already searched for the solution, but still nothing, maybe I could help.

Answer (score 25):

Solved the problem by making a small change to the build.gradle file. Basically just change the order, calling first maven {} and then jcenter ()

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
             url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make the change in the 'allprojects' section also, to get it to build.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by removing

```
maven {
     url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

in the `allprojects { repositeries{ ... } }` lines below the `buildscript { ... }` lines.

Then, I add `google()` before `jcenter()` like that :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So in platforms/android/build.gradle file,it should be something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use Gradle plugin version 4 or higher, use:

```
google()
```

otherwise use:

```
maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"` and it was because of that!
I removed it and it started to build again!

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue a few days ago solved via :

**Go to platform/android/build.gradle**

Move google to upside in **buildscripts** as well as in **allprojects**

**For example**

```
maven {
     url "https://maven.google.com"
}
jcenter()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain from where the problem arises but it can be solved by Invalidatind caches and restart,

goto

File and select invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Not every problem can solve using `Invalidate caches and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was in *incorrect or outdated*(?) plugin de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification, that I  installed **recently**

I **removed** this plugin de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

Than install **other version** 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification

Ionic 3 codebase
Ionic 6* cli version

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to latest version

Answer (score 0):

1. install java 8
2. setup your environment variable
   .
3. go to android studio click file->project structure->project settings->project.
4. select project sdk "which should be the sdk you are .
5. click apply then ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar challenge. Apparently, I had added a dysfunctional dependency that was throwing that build error. What I did was that I scrolled downward in the build output and I saw the dependency that was giving me the error, something like, "couldn't find com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3"

I simply deleted that dependency and my app started running again.

Comment: removing dependency `com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3` is not solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, VPN was not allowed to download dependencies.